# Что за объект kqemu virtualisation module for qemu ?

Tags: windows, windows-7, виртуальная-машина

Всем доброго времени суток.

OC: Win7
У меня ни с того ни с сего в списке установленных программ оказалась **"kqemu virtualisation module for qemu"**. Я немного порылся в интете, не густо конечно, но все таки нашел людей что используют эту виртуальную машину. Я уверен, что ее не устанавливал да и вообще виртуальных машин не использовал. 
Продукт о себе, не несет никакой информации:

```
Program Name: KQEMU virtualisation module for QEMU

Program Information
===================

Program Size: [Not available]
Install Date: [Not available]
Last Access: [Not available]
Install Location: [Not available]
Install Source: [Not available]
Version: [Not available]

Support Information
===================
Publisher: [Not available]
Help Info: [Not available]
About Info: [Not available]
Update Info: [Not available]
Telephone: [Not available]

DisplayName=KQEMU virtualisation module for QEMU
UninstallString=RunDll32 setupapi.dll,InstallHinfSection Uninstall 132 %SystemRoot%\inf\kqemu.inf
```

Подозрительный объект 1ним словом. Стоит мне его опасаться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничего страшного нет. Просто, скорее всего, Вы ставили что-то, с чем в комплекте шел qemu-manager. Если не используете виртуальных машин, в частности kvm-qemu, то можно и снести. Но лучше посмотреть, какая программулька потащила за собой данный менеджер.

Comment: А как мне вычислить эту "программульку"?) Где то в журнале, истории Windows? Можно уточнить?

Comment: Если только по дате установки смотреть. Ну или посмотрите в запущенных службах. Если там запущена одноименная служба, то попробуйте выключить.